# BroadcastHub instances on Websocket connection are not cleaned up after disconnect

Tags: scala, websocket, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a web applications that is only available on an intranet.
It serves data to the frontend asynchronously via Websocket.
However, running it for a while will create multiple instances of BroadcastHub and not clean all of them up.
Furthermore, the cache of the BroadcastHub fills up on some connections.
This points to the client being disconnected.
Over time this will exhaust the memory of the Java VM.
I already use the poisonPill and from the logs it looks like its correctly invoked.
But the BroadcastHub and its cache stay alive and are not cleaned up by the GC.

Can anyone help?

Here is the code that create the Flow for handling Websocket data.

```
val (actor, source) =
      // producer is materialized ActorRef
      Source.actorRef[String](10, akka.stream.OverflowStrategy.dropTail)
      .named(WebServer.socketWelcomeFlowName)
      // attach a BroadcastHub Sink to the producer
      .toMat(BroadcastHub.sink[String])(Keep.both)
      // By running/materializing the producer, we get back a Source, which
      // gives us access to the elements published by the producer
      .run()

connectedClients += 1
log.info(s"New client session with path: ${actor.path}.")
communication.welcomeNewClient(actor, log)(10 seconds, IO.contextShift(blockingIO)).unsafeRunAsync(_ => {})
communication.tellTopUserActor(log)(GenericMessageGalliumAdapterActor.name, GenericMessageGalliumAdapterActor.NewClientConnected).unsafeRunSync()

Flow[ws.Message]
  .watchTermination() { (m, f) =>
    f.onComplete(_ => {
      log.info(s"Client session '${actor.path}' left.")
      actor ! PoisonPill
      connectedClients -= 1
      }
    )
    m
  }
  .merge(source)
  .map {
    case TextMessage.Strict(tm) => handleMessage(actor, tm).map(Future.successful)
    case PassThroughMessage(tm) => Some(Future.successful(tm))
    case _ => Some(Future.successful(TextMessage.Strict("Gallium can only handle TextMessages for now!")))
  }
  .filter(_.isDefined)
  .map(_.get)
  .mapAsync(parallelism = 3)(identity)
```

After feedback, I updated it to:

```
  Source.actorRef[String]({
      case akka.actor.Status.Success(s: CompletionStrategy) => s
      case akka.actor.Status.Success(_)                     => CompletionStrategy.immediately
      case akka.actor.Status.Success                        => CompletionStrategy.immediately
      case akka.actor.Status.Failure                        => CompletionStrategy.immediately
    }, { case akka.actor.Status.Failure(cause)              => cause }
      , 10, OverflowStrategy.fail)
```

Comment: You should probably use the non-deprecated version of `ActorRef` and provide appropriate completion and failure matchers.

Comment: I used akka 2.5.x where this was not marked deprecated.
I updated to 2.7.0 and
      Source.actorRef[String]({
          case akka.actor.Status.Success(s: CompletionStrategy) => s
          case akka.actor.Status.Success(_)                     => CompletionStrategy.immediately
          case akka.actor.Status.Success                        => CompletionStrategy.immediately
          case akka.actor.Status.Failure                        => CompletionStrategy.immediately
        }, { case akka.actor.Status.Failure(cause)              => cause }
          , 10, OverflowStrategy.fail)